# How to add taxonomy to user?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

I added some custom taxonomy to a CPT with:

```php
register_taxonomy( 'sport', 'activity', [
        'label'     => 'Sport',
        'rewrite'   => [ 'slug' => 'sport'],
        'hierarchical' => true
    ]);
```

and this works fine. The taxonomy also shows up in the admin menu, as a subpage for activity.

Then I wanted to do the same for the users:

```php
    register_taxonomy( 'team', 'user', [
        'label'     => 'Team',
        'rewrite'   => [ 'slug' => 'team'],
        'hierarchical' => true
    ]);
```

However this did not work for me, the taxonomy did not show up in the admin menu.
After some research, I could make it appear with this code

```php
function add_user_tax_menu() {
    $tax = get_taxonomy( 'team' );
    add_users_page(
        esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ),
        esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ),
        $tax->cap->manage_terms,
        'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $tax->name
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_user_tax_menu');
```

But it still does not work properly. For example if click on the link in the `count` column, I end up in the posts sections, with no posts listed.
I guess I have to somehow tell WP that the type is `user` and not `post`, but I cannot figure out how.

I also tried using `'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $tax->name . '&post_type=user'` instead, but that didn't work either (maybe because user isn't a post type?).

### Update

With the help of the answer posted by @saqib-ali and the tutorial mentioned in the comment, I got somewhat closer to to a solution. However, I still cannot see which users are assigned to a `team`. When I click on the link in the `Count` column (see screenshot) I end up back in the `posts` section of the admin panel.

[image]

The link points to

```
.../wp-admin/edit.php?team=team-a
```

My guess is, that it needs to be changed to

```
.../wp-admin/users.php?team=team-a
```

according to the mentioned tutorial, this might be done with the `manage_circle_custom_column` hook. But I could not find a hook like that in the WP doc (only `manage_posts_custom_column`). So maybe that hook doesn't exist (anymore)?

And then I would probably also need to add a filter hook that filters users by the taxonomy in the query parameter. Similar to how it works for the role

```
.../wp-admin/users.php?role=administrator
```

I couldn't yet find the appropriate hook for either task.

Comment: note that WP doesn't provide a UI for user taxonomies, but adding it isn't difficult, take a look at http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress

Comment: This is an excellent tutorial for this, it's a little dated and the comments seem to be now disabled. One of the crucial steps in the tutorial refers to a comment by "James". I checked archive.org and that comment basically suggests the hook/function posted by @saqib-ali on this question here. 
The tutorial didn't solve my issue completely, but at least pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There comes a hook in wordpress named Parent File (Filters the parent file of an admin menu sub-menu item) read more about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parent_file/)

In your case it goes like:

```
add_filter('parent_file', 'parent_menu');

function parent_menu($parent = '') {
    global $pagenow;
    
    if(!empty($_GET['taxonomy']) && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && $_GET['taxonomy'] == 'category') {
        $parent = 'edit.php';
    }
     /*If we're editing one of the user taxonomies
    We must be within the users menu, so highlight that*/
    if(!empty($_GET['taxonomy']) && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && $_GET['taxonomy'] == 'team') {
        $parent = 'users.php';
    }
    
    return $parent;
}
```

Hope that it solves your problem.

Comment: This brought me a step closer, but unfortunately not all the way there. The links in the `Count` column still point to posts instead of users

Comment: I updated the question with more information

Comment: @jost21 for this you need to select count of taxonomies by wpdb query and then have to manage it accordingly. Seems tough? take a look at [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lh-user-taxonomies/) plugin it does your work. and try to look up in the code as well.